# 301 Redirects and Link Values

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, pagerank

I recently moved my website to a new domain but seems like the link values are not passed till yet. I researched it a bit and found on Moz documentation that it may take sometime before the link values are passed to the new domain. Any ideas on how much time it can take? Any way to expedite it?

Comment: While it may be tempting to hurry Google up, I say resist at all costs! Using a 301 redirect can take months sometimes. Most of this is based upon the popularity of the site, how trendy it is (news, celebrity), your trust scores and overall Pagerank, etc. Hot sites get more attention. Sorry. Just the way it is. Cheers!!

Comment: Have you informed Google Search Console a [change of address](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en)? This should had followed as soon as you had setup the 301 redirects.

Answer (score 0):

You request re-indexing and/or re-submit your sitemap. It will take between a few days and a few weeks. [You can read more about it here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en)